# Show two different information in one plot, using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if it is possible to show two different information in one plot?

So what I mean is, lets say I have a simple dataset like this:

`library(ggplot2)
 values = c(1,4,6,7,8,2,3,9,9,8)
 x = 1:10`

So I can draw this simple function using

```
 data=data.frame(x, values)
 ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=values)) + geom_line()
```

So now comes my problem, I also have another information / another y-vector telling me for each entry, if it is inside some interesting subset, so something like:

```
 more_info = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes")
```

I would like this other information to be drawn over my function like color boxes (the blue boxes stand for yes). [image]

I have tried it with a geom_bar() however - this is not exactly what I want, since it will draw for each entry one bar - I would like to have bars like in the figure, if they are 3 consecutive yes - they should be shown with one colored box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding multiple shadows/rectangles to ggplot2 graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741703/adding-multiple-shadows-rectangles-to-ggplot2-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_rect` to draw rectangles.  First, I use `dplyr` to add a `no` column, which will match your `x` column whenever the `more_info` column is set to "no":

```
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(x, values, more_info) %>% 
  mutate(no = ifelse(more_info == "no", x, NA))
data$no[1:2] = NA # because you wanted to remove the leading no's
```

And here is the plot (I made the rectangles start half a space before a *no* and end half a space after the end of a *no*):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=values)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = no - 0.5, xmax = no + 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.2, fill = "purple")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much. It took me a while to understand what you wrote, but now i am very grateful for this simple solution.

Comment: @malajedala I got confused because you said you wanted to highlight the yes rows, but your example highlights the no rows. Anyway, I'm glad I could help in the end.